# How to know where the domains point to in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dns

If I ping google.com, for example, I got:

Pinging google.com [173.194.38.130] with 32 bytes of d
Reply from 173.194.38.130: bytes=32 time=1033ms TTL=56
Reply from 173.194.38.130: bytes=32 time=1004ms TTL=56
Reply from 173.194.38.130: bytes=32 time=518ms TTL=56

That means google.com points to 173.194.38.130

How to do so with vb.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best option is to use `Dns.GetHostEntry` Method.

```
Dim hostNameOrAddress As String = "google.com"
Dim returnValue As IPHostEntry

returnValue = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostNameOrAddress)
```

[More info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms143998%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)